# Status Bar Android Studio

Tags: android

Como faço para abrir um app ao fazer o movimento da status bar vou criar um app estilo o "inoty" como faço pra fazer ele ficar sempre ativo e abrir igual uma barra de status ao fazer o movimento

Comment: Não entendi a sua pergunta, pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito mal formulada.

Comment: Você tem que criar uma notificação de alta prioridade e não deixar o usuário remove-la.